# Partial Fraction Decomposition for Integral Solution

Tags: calculus

I have a problem solving the following integral :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\upsilon\;x}\:x^{\mu -1}}{\left ( x+a \right )^{m}\left ( x+b \right )^{n}}\:dx$$
This integral can by solved by using partial fraction decomposition for the following: 
$$\frac{1}{\left ( x+a \right )^{m}\left ( x+b \right )^{n}}$$
where $\mu$, $m$, and $n$ are integers numbers, $a> 0$ and  $b> 0$.

However, I couldn't find a general formula for the partial fraction decomposition above to simplify the integral.

Looking for a solution for the integral using partial fraction decomposition or any other methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but maybe you should approach this problem in the following way
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(x+a)^{n}(x+b)^{m}} & = \frac{1}{b-a}\frac{(x+b) - (x+a)}{(x+a)^{n}(x+b)^{m}}\\
& = \frac{1}{b-a}\frac{1}{(x+a)^{n}(x+b)^{m-1}} + \frac{1}{b-a}\frac{1}{(x+a)^{n-1}(x+b)^{m}}
\end{align*}

Perhaps there is some recurrence relation to find out the result.